# sudo: command not found error while executing aws ecr get-login-password in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, containers, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, podman

I am trying to create a Podman container image using Azure pipelines, below is my repo structure:

BuildContainerPipeline contains these files ==>`azure-pipelines.yml`, `ContainerImage.yml`, `dockerFile`

1. azure-pipelines.yml ==> this contains some basic checks and refers to template-containerimage.yml to build container image (refer to the below .yml script)

```
#Starter pipeline

trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - main
      - feature/*

pool: DEV-AWS

variables:
- name: region
  value: "us-west-2"

jobs:
  - job: clean_workspace_job
    workspace:
      clean: all
    condition: always()
    steps:
      - checkout: none
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: clean task
        inputs:
          script: |
            echo "Cleaning workspace"

  - deployment: Build_Container 
    displayName: Build Container
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - task: CmdLine@2
              displayName: List Agent Directory
              inputs:
                script: |
                  set -ex
                  ls -alh $AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY
                  ls -alh $AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY/s

            - template: ContainerImage.yml
```

2. ContainerImage.yml ==> this contains aws and podman commands that creates image and push to AWS ECR (refer to the below docker file)

```
parameters:
  - name: region
    type: string
    default: "us-west-2"
  - name: displayName
    type: string
    default: "Build Agent Container"
  - name: imageName
    type: string
    default: "aws-ado-agent"
  - name: ECRName
    type: string
    default: "xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
  - name: workingDir
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: dockerFileDirPath
    type: string
    default: "$AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY/s"
  - name: dockerFileName
    type: string
    default: dockerFile

steps:
  - task: CmdLine@2
    name: Build_Container
    displayName: ${{parameters.displayName}}
    inputs:
      script: |
        set -ex
        #curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
        echo "start Image build"
        sudo aws ecr get-login-password --region ${{parameters.region}}|sudo podman login --username AWS --password-stdin ${{parameters.ECRName}}
        cd ${{parameters.dockerFileDirPath}}
        VERSION=$(Build.BuildNumber)
        IMAGE_NAME=${{parameters.imageName}}
        sudo podman build --format docker -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:v$VERSION -f ${{parameters.dockerFileName}} .
        sudo podman tag 12345 xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_NAME}:v$VERSION
        sudo  podman tag 12345 xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_NAME}
        sudo  podman push xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_NAME}:v$VERSION
        sudo podman push xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_NAME}
        sudo podman rmi xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_NAME}:v$VERSION
        sudo podman rmi xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_NAME}
        sudo podman image prune -a;
      workingDirectory: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.workingDir}}"
```

3. `dockerFile` ==> contains podman, aws cli and other project required softwares installation steps

```
FROM docker.io/redhat/ubi8

--------
podman
--------

---------
hashicorp 
---------

--------
chef
--------

--------
aws cli
--------
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install
RUN rm awscliv2.zip

----------
dotnet sdk
----------

ENTRYPOINT
```

When I run the pipeline, I am encountering below error at `sudo aws ecr command` step

**Pipleines Log**

```
2023-06-14T18:37:45.5290477Z + echo 'start Image build'
2023-06-14T18:37:45.5291301Z start Image build
2023-06-14T18:37:45.5297827Z + sudo aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2
2023-06-14T18:37:45.5298877Z /azp/_work/_temp/521f6503-49e0-4042-824a-bf462fb122aa.sh: line 5: sudo: command not found
2023-06-14T18:37:45.5302500Z + sudo podman login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
2023-06-14T18:37:45.5303506Z /azp/_work/_temp/521f6503-49e0-4042-824a-bf462fb122aa.sh: line 5: sudo: command not found
2023-06-14T18:37:45.5376216Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
```

NOTE: The `BuildContainerPipeline` is executing on containerized azure agent which is created used Terraform script

I have tried searching for this error and could not find the exact use case but many blogs/stackoverflow pointed out that awscli might not be installed on container image which is why command not found error been thrown.

`awscli` installation has been already included in my `dockerFile`, how do I fix this error? Is there anything missing on my `dockerFile`? ContainerImage.yml? I appreciate your input on this issue.

Comment: It seems obvious that `sudo` isn't available in that build environment. I would try removing `sudo` from your commands and see if they work without it.

Comment: @MarkB, I have tried removing sudo and executed in separate lines, aws ecr command was successful but podman command failed with error
`2023-06-15T13:20:17.3250441Z cannot clone: Operation not permitted
2023-06-15T13:20:17.3251625Z Error: cannot re-exec process
2023-06-15T13:20:17.3307351Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '125'.`